# (Text Strings must be rendered with in a <Text> component. Render Error ) React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here is my code.

```
<FlatList
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={ModalData}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => {
              return (
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    marginBottom: 10,
                    marginHorizontal: 10,
                  }}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flexDirection: 'column',
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                    }}>
                    {item.icon}
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: '#3B3B3B',
                        fontFamily: fonts.UbuntuNormal,
                        padding: 10,
                      }}>
                      {item.title}
                      {index.key}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
              );
            }}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          />
```

Please Help me I'm Stuck Here..

Answer (score 0):

check your text closing tag which is properly closed or not
check that rendering the text is inside {rendering_text_data}
in here there is an issue on renderItem that you are not properly closing it, check it and always try to share the code snippet with question with formatted code so it will be easy to understand